# Run a query to a lotus notes database from C #

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I need to run a (select * from table) in a Lotus Notes database using as a programming language c #, I would be very grateful if someone helps me with the code, since I'm new to the company and I don't know anything about lotus note. Whereas I have a Local database and the database file is called test.nsf. and the password to the lotus is (Osrami28).

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place to come and have people write your code for you. There is a NotesSQL driver. There is documentation for it. It might work for you. Look it up. Try it. If you have problems, come back to StackOverflow and ask a specific question about the specific problem. But really, SQL is probably the worst of the many ways to access Notes data, and your statement "I need to run a select * tells me that you are thinking only in terms of what you already know, so the first problem that you really need to solve - before you write code - is "I don't know anything about lotus notes".

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is using Domino Query Language ([DQL](https://doc.cwpcollaboration.com/appdevpack/docs/en/domino-query-language.html)) from Javascript using Node.js and the [AppDev](https://doc.cwpcollaboration.com/appdevpack/docs/en/homepage.html) pack.  The SELECT clause in this case is in the domino-db API and the WHERE clause is DQL.  This requires V10 of Domino.